# Adjusting flow direction of river based on DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, rivers, flow, flow-direction

I have a huge vector layer as a line, that represents the river. The problem is that the flow direction is sometimes wrong (goes uphill). But I can't correct that manually, cause the layer is too big.

I also have a DEM for the entire area. So is it a way to reverse only the lines that go uphill? I mean something like selecting the line that the `end_point` is at a higher altitude than the `start_point`, and flipping the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

1. Use [select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#selecting-features) with this expression where DEM is the name of your raster layer (digital elevation model):

   ```
   raster_value ('DEM', 1, start_point ($geometry)) <
   raster_value ('DEM', 1, end_point ($geometry))
   ```
2. Then [reverse line direction](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#reverse-line-direction) for selected features (see screenshot below).

### Solution 2

You could also do it directly in one step with [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression), creating a new layer:

```
if (
    raster_value( 'DEM', 1, start_point ($geometry)) <
    raster_value( 'DEM', 1, end_point ($geometry)),
    reverse( $geometry),
    $geometry
)
```

---

*The line at the botten right will be selected:*
[image]